# Cannot create new Property in DirectoryEntry class for Active Directory

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to put a new Active Directory user in a new Active Directory group. Normally you can do something like this:

```
DirectoryEntry groupEntry = ......;
groupEntry.Properties["member"].Add(userEntry);
groupEntry.CommitChanges();
```

Now the problem is that a **new** AD group does not have the "member" property; the above code will therefore throw you an exception. When you manually add a user to a group in Active Directory, the "member" property will be created automatically. But there is no way I can **create** the "member" property in code; the Properties property is read-only and also an InvokeSet("member", new List()) or something similar throws me an exception.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to create a non-existing property for an AD entry?

PS: as the user is also new, he doesn't have the "memberOf" property: this will generate the exact same problem.

Comment: This is a related question. Does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143052/adding-and-removing-users-from-active-directory-groups-in-net

Comment: Yes... I finally got it working using that new approach - many thanks!