# Why am I getting "No security object matching the specified parameters found" error (GroupPrincipal)

Tags: c#, .net, principalcontext, groupprincipal

I'm creating a program that adds and removes **domain users** to/from **local groups** on a specific computer.

I successfully finished part that adds users to group, but when it comes to removing I'm getting this error.

> Exception thrown: 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException' in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.NoMatchingPrincipalException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.dll
>   Additional information: No security object matching the specified parameters found

**Here is my function and example of what variables can contain**

```
string username = "USER123"
string localGroupName = "Administrators"
string computername = "computer1"
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine,computername))
{
    GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, localGroupName);

    group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.Name, username);
    group.Save();
}
```

I also tried to change IdentityType, but got same result

```
group.Members.Remove(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, username);
```

I can print all members of any group using foreach so I presume everything up to a "GroupPrincipal" is correct.

It seems like I'm putting in wrong username, but the username is correct (I'm using it to logon into a computer that is in domain) and using bellow formula did not help either.

> DomainName\UserName

Also I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802849/remove-domain-user-from-local-groups) thread, but to me it seems like almost the same thing, but written differently.

**Any help or ideas is greatly appreciated! Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but I'm using C# only for a while.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for my problem. Maybe it can help to someone so I'm posting it here.

```
string computername = "computer1"
string groupName = "Administrators"
string usernameToRemove = "testUser"
using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Machine, computername))
  using (GroupPrincipal localGroup = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Name, groupname))
    foreach (Principal groupUser in localGroup.GetMembers())
        if (groupUser.SamAccountName == usernameToRemove)
        {
            localGroup.Members.Remove(groupUser);
            localGroup.Save();
        }
```

More or less I edited answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802849/remove-domain-user-from-local-groups) question. His solution is does not search through all members of a group as mine(if I undestand his code correctly), but working solution is working solution.